# Ubuntu 20.04 Webcam Flickering On/Off

Tags: webcam, camera

I am running **Ubuntu 22.04 LTS** and my webcam seems to be blinking on and off. Doesn't seem to be a hardware issue since works as intended on Windows 11 (Dual boot system).
The webcam I have is a *Microdia Webcam Vitade AF*.

Running `lsusb` shows my webcam in the list of devices.

*I tried restarting the camera by using:*
`sudo mod probe -r uvcvideo`
`sudo modprobe a uvcvideo`
Yet, it still seems to be blinking on and off.
When I test it and go to Cheese it bugs and captures a few frames and loops it infinitely.

Is the webcam simply faulty with this operating system or is there something I need to do to enable it properly?

Comment: The same issue with StarBook Mk V. It works well with other apps, so I guess it is a Cheese issue.